# Не отображается русский язык в asp.net core + angular

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net, asp.net-core

Создаю проект ASP.NET Core 2.0 + Angular [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При добавлении в любой из существующих компонентов русских слов, к примеру в home.component.html выходит такое [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ничего больше в проекте я не изменял, в _Layout.cshtml указана кодировка utf-8. Как исправить эту проблему?

Comment: посмотрите еще текущую кодировку в браузере. (обычно вкладка "вид")

Comment: Такая же проблема на других компьютерах. Остальные типы проектов работают без проблем, только с ангуляром такое.

Comment: вот видос на ютубе, мне помогло https://youtu.be/l1StsiDHRo0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тебе нужно пересохранить все файлы `.ts` и `.html` в `UTF-8`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не помогло.

Comment: @ИльяМосийчук, только что перепроверил у себя, все работает.

Answer (score 2):

Для поддержки русского языка в `HTML` страницах, вам надо указать кодировку явно в `<head>` тегах вашего сайта.

Для этого укажите следующий META-тег:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Также нужно учесть кодировку самого файла, как вам указали в другом ответе.

Также вы можете это сделать в файле `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: В web.config и HTML указана кодировка, но не работает.